# text-align justify spacing still not work with word-spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have paragraph inside my div and one i use  text-align: justify; its have a spaces between words and whatever i do its not fixed it even word-spacing

here my html

```
<div class="work span3">
    <img src="../../Content/Images/LastWork/Real local industry.jpg" alt="" class="example-image">
    <h4>Real local industry
    </h4>
    <p>
        Tharwa Breda Petroleum Service company is one of the petroleum sector companies  launched its local production for the well head and X-mas trees in Nov. , 2012 to be the first company in Egypt and Middle East working and Certified as API-6A for this kind of industry .This Project is a part of oil ministry and Egyptian government plan for economic independence and self sufficiency which are the legitimate objectives for our nation to pursue.
    </p>
    <div class="icon-awesome">
        <a href="../../Content/Images/LastWork/Real local industry.jpg" data-lightbox=" example-1">
            <i class="icon-search"></i>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

and here the css

```
.portfolio .work
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E6170D;
    float: left;
    height: 590px;
    margin-left: 32px !important;
    padding: 5px 5px 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 20% !important;
}
.portfolio .work p
{
    font-size: 12PX;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

nothing effect the space with 20% width i have to make the div bigger to work and i cant do that

Comment: I can't see something wrong in your example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lyjonp9/

Comment: What is .portfolio in your HTML / CSS code ? Can you provide some code about it ?

Comment: as @emmanuel told it looks perfect. I would suggest you to clean the cache and start again , may be it helps.

Comment: The code shown does not contain `text-justify: align` or `word-spacing` at all.